# Extract 1:n relation from PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, foreign-keys

Suppose i have two such tables

```
| items |          | translations |
|_______|          |______________|
| id    |<---\     | id           |
| name  |     \--->| head_id      |
|_______|          | translation  |
                   |______________|
```

I have set of item's ids which i need to extract along with their translations. I think i can extract ids like this:

```
$ids = implode(', ', $input->ids);
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM items WHERE id IN ($ids)";
$resultIds = pg_query($dbconn, $query) or die(pg_last_error());
```

And now i need to get all translations for every item. And i can only think of looping through all ids and query translations for every single id. Is there a better way to do it?

---

While writing the post another idea came to mind. I can do three selects, one for ids as shown above, second and third like

```
$query2 = "SELECT items.id, translations.id 
           FROM items, translations 
           WHERE items.id = translations.head_id and items.id IN ($ids)";

$query3 = "SELECT translations.id, translation
           FROM items, translations 
           WHERE items.id = translations.head_id and items.id IN ($ids)";
```

And then these three results contain all needed info and no more than needed.

Comment: Why not just include the `item.name` in the joined queries? Then you have all the information and combined. You can have more than two columns in your resultset.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i'll end up with a lot of repetitions then, that's 1:n relation

Comment: So then group it up in php to a 2d array grouped under the duplicated value. Or use a `group_concat` equivalent to concat the values together.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i'm new to PHP and Postgres, i'll investigate `group_concat` option, thanks

Comment: `group_concat` is a mysql thing, but I'm sure postgres has an equivalent. And having one query that returns multiple values with duplicates is going to be a thousand times better than running multiple queries, especially if it is something like one per row.